# Websphere MQ- How to find the total number of messages that pass througha queue manager

Tags: ibm-mq

Is there a way to find the total number of messages that pass through an IBM websphere MQ queue manager over a specific period of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect use of the MQ Accounting and Statistics feature. Among other things, these features record the number of messages (with a persistent and non-persistent count) and also number of bytes (not all messages are the same size).

You can turn on Accounting and Statistics for just a selection of queues and/or channels or for everything.

Further Reading:

- [Accounting and statistics messages](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q037240_.htm)
- [Turning on Queue Accounting](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q037290_.htm)
- [Turning on Queue Statistics](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q037360_.htm)
- [Supplied tool to view the output](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q037390_.htm)